# Fatal error and no more info in Prestashop 1.6.1.11

Tags: php, prestashop, cpanel, fatal-error, whm

From time to time i get "Fatal error" with no more info during checkout on my Prestashop 1.6.1.11 installation.

I have tried to set php max memory to 512 (was 128), but still the error shows up.
I'm on a vps with whm/cPanel and run it myself.

How can i best investigate this issue? I find no clue about it in the error_log, like I would if it was an 500-error or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the mode developer to see an explanation of the error.

You need to edit the file "defines.inc.php" and set the "_PS_MODE_DEV_" to true, like this:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

Comment: Yes I know. I had it activated for a long time (on a production site), but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. However I got some very strange other thing happening during the time I had dev mode activated: 
Sometimes the whole page would echo <pre>print_r()</pre> all available information on the site, and nothing else.